# gcc cold function attribute vs builtin_expect behavior

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, compiler-optimization

from gcc function attribute: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html
the cold attribute can hint gcc partition caller's cold to 2 part: normal part(the hold part) and cold part into separation function

> cold
>
> The cold attribute on functions is used to inform the compiler that the function is unlikely to be executed. The function is optimized for size rather than speed and on many targets it is placed into a special subsection of the text section so all cold functions appear close together, improving code locality of non-cold parts of program. The paths leading to calls of cold functions within code are marked as unlikely by the branch prediction mechanism. It is thus useful to mark functions used to handle unlikely conditions, such as perror, as cold to improve optimization of hot functions that do call marked functions in rare occasions.
>
> When profile feedback is available, via -fprofile-use, cold functions are automatically detected and this attribute is ignored.

and here is a example https://godbolt.org/z/j7sK4hd48

however, other hint like *__builtin_expect(int , int)* cannot hint compiler to such optimization, instead, compiler only place *unexpected* at bottom of the function. but not separate them and split to another function which just like function attribute *cold* do.

is GCC planing to support such optimization for *__builtin_expect* ?
if not, can we do other effort to implement such effect ?

in other side, the Clang seems don't support such split hot/cold cod to separate function, or maybe I'm missing ?

Comment: `is GCC planing to` That's a question rather for some gcc mailing list or to some gcc developer, rather then on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, The LLVM already support this optimzations.The LLVM have option hot-cold-split=true to do this.And in the x86 backEnd, there is a option -split-machine-functions to do this.

Comment: But in the gcc, it is composed several passes to achieved that result,like static branch predict or profile guide, bb-reorder and ipa-split, Not just one pass.

Comment: `-fsplit-machine-functions`: Enable late function splitting using profile information (x86 ELF) might help